# Getting the x-y position of selected text using rangy-position.js

Tags: javascript, html, range, rangy, getselection

I am trying to find the x-y position of the starting point of my selection.
I have tried to use rangy-position.js(http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/position.html)  and have also included the supporting js files required by it.

Following is the script which I have included on my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showSelectionPosition() {
         var wholeSelRectEl, startSelEl, endSelEl;
        // Draw an element representing the whole selection rectangle
        var wholeSelRect = rangy.getSelection().getBoundingDocumentRect();

        //removeSelectionIndicators();

        if (!wholeSelRect) {
            return;
        }
        var startPos = rangy.getSelection().getStartDocumentPos();


        alert("y pos:" + startPos.y);

        var endPos = rangy.getSelection().getEndDocumentPos();
    } 

</script>
```

On mouseup showSelectionPosition() is called as follows:

```
$('#container').mouseup(function(f) {
    showSelectionPosition();

});
```

Also note that #container contains a lot of div elements in it which finally have the text which I want to select.
The problem is I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of null
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the selection in a range and then use getBoundingDocumentRect() on it.

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
var rect = range.getBoundingDocumentRect();
alert("y pos:" + rect.top);
```